# Экспорт из буфера обмена в таблицу и в базу данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql

У меня вопрос.
Есть документ эксель или  таблица ворда с полями (например):

> ФИО/Зачётка/Пасспорт/Студенческий/Дом.адр и др.

Пользователь копирует данные из документа в буфер обмена.
Нажимает на кнопку "Сохранить". И содержимое буфера обмена сохраняется в базу данных.
Как сосчитать содержимое буфера и подвязать его к запросу `insert`?

Comment: Бред какой-то... не говоря уж о грамматике

Comment: Очень остроумно! если не понимаешь и не знаешь что писать, какой прикол писать, что это бред.
Помоему написал нормально, по крайней мере можно уж переспросить....

Answer (score 3):

В вашем вопросе нет практически никакой информации о базе данных, да и не так это просто скопировать таблицу из MS Office Word, как мне кажется, а затем представить её в нужном виде. Для примера, если есть связь с тем вопросом, что вы задавали по поводу занесения данных из таблицы в буфер обмена (где разделителями являются точки с запятой, а строки разделяются переводом строки), то можно привести следующий код:

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string[] data = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                data[i] = data[i].Remove(data[i].Length - 1, 1); // удаляем '\r'

            int lengthRow = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data[0].Length; i++)
                if (data[0].IndexOf(';', i) != -1)
                    lengthRow++;

            string insertString = "insert into " + tableName + " values(";
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthRow; i++)
                insertString += "@" + (char)(i + 97) + ", "; // 97 - a, 98 - b и т.д.
            insertString = insertString.Remove(insertString.Length - 2, 2); // удаляем ", " из конца
            insertString += ");";

            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertString, connection);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] values = data[i].Split(';');
                insertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < lengthRow; j++)
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + (char)(i + 97), values[j]);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Когда-то он справлялся с поставленной задачей. Код на правах "ИМХО", сильно не ругайте. Здесь я формирую строку "insert into %tableName% values([[@a](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha), [[[[@b](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley), ... [@n](/users/12/null));", подставляя затем вместо [[@a](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha), [[[[@b](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) и другие "переменные" конкретные значения.

Comment: не очень понятно......таблица,например студентов (Зачётка,Фио,студенческий)
я в экселе копирую таблицу в буфер обмена точно в таком же виде (зачётка,фио,студенческий) и надо первую ячейку вставить зачётку...и т.д.
тоесть цикл, чтоб вытаскивал из буфера и формировал строку запроса....

Comment: BULK INSERT может лучше,не?

Comment: Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n'); - вытаскивает твой текст, делит на строки. Потом проходит по строкам, делит каждую строку на массив значений, затем формирует insert-запрос и подставляет под именованные переменные конкретные значения, затем выполняет запрос, "чистит" значения и так для каждой строки.

Насчёт BULK INSERT - не разбирался.

Comment: Выругивается....
Значение StartIndex не может быть меньше нуля.
Имя параметра: startIndex

Comment: В каком месте-то?

Comment: да, тут косяк с lengthRow есть, извиняюсь, нужно по-другому получать количество записей, примерно так:
    int lengthRow = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < data[0].Length; i++)
        if(data[0][i] == ';')
             lengthRow++;

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое буффера обмена  доступно через [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard_methods(v=vs.90).aspx),

Как видно, в буффер обмена может хранить одновременно (и независимо): текст, картинку, звук, cписок файлов и общие данные (data)
Но с excel: я не уверен на 100% - он при копировании если я не ошибюсь копирует с экрана ячейки как картинку и сохраняет в буффере обмена картинку, а саму структуру ячеек в Data. Причем не сразу понятно в каком она там виде.

Поэтому если попытатся вставить в какойнить paint (кстати не пробовал) то вставится картинка. И только Office будет знать как расшифровать то что лежит в data. может так хмл, а может при копировании текста он будет читаем:)

Кстати я делал [программку](http://download.ru/products/paster) когдато=) 
Но на ворде у меня время закончилось. документ создать смог, а как понять что в буффере обмена кусок ворда/экселя/аксесса/т.п. не знал на то время. а счас времени нет